# Change specific NumPy array to be coordinate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I want to change the NumPy array from `[x0 y0 x1 y1]` to be `[(y0, x0) (x1, y1)]`.

I already tried many things but still not found the right way.

This was my code:

```
import glob
import os
import cv2
import time
import dlib
import face_detection
import numpy as np
import inspect

print(inspect.getsource(dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()))

print(dlib.__file__) 

def draw_faces(im, bboxes):
    for bbox in bboxes:
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = [int(_) for _ in bbox]
        #cv2.rectangle(im, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        image = cv2.rectangle(im, pt1=(x0, y0), pt2=(x1, y1), color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=4)       
        conv = np.array(((x0, y0), (x1, y1)))
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    impaths = "images"
    impaths = glob.glob(os.path.join(impaths, "*.jpg"))
    detector = face_detection.build_detector(
        "DSFDDetector",
        max_resolution=1080
    )
    for impath in impaths:
        if impath.endswith("out.jpg"): continue
        im = cv2.imread(impath)
        print("Processing:", impath)
        t = time.time()
        dets = detector.detect(
            im[:, :, ::-1]
        )[:, :4]

        conv = np.array(dets, dtype=int)
        conv1= np.split(conv, [1,2])
                    
        draw_faces(im, dets)
        print(conv1)
    
        print(f"Detection time: {time.time()- t:.3f}")
        
        imname = os.path.basename(impath).split(".")[0]
        output_path = os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(impath),
            f"{imname}_out.jpg"
        )

        cv2.imwrite(output_path, im)
```

The item I want to change comes from `face_detection.build_detector ()`

Comment: Making sure it's not a typo -- you want to flip the `x` and `y`, but only for the first tuple?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response,
Yes it's. that's necessary for next step program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for converting NumPy array into a list of two tuples:

```
a = np.array((1, 2, 3, 4))
b = [tuple(a[0:2]), tuple(a[2:4])]
```

I hope I understand your question (the code you posted in not minimal reproducible sample).